# How Do I escape a column name like "Supervisory?" in an SQL prepared Statement?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, spring, prepared-statement

I have a java application that is using DAOs that wrap `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`
The database has table names and column names that need to be escaped with `[]` for the queries to work properly and that's fine.  However, one of my Columns has a **?** as part of the column name.  So if I try to run the query below:

```sql
INSERT INTO [Supervisory Description]([Supervisory?], Description)  
       VALUES ( :id, :description );
```

I get the following Exception, listed at the bottom of this question.
The important part is:

```java
InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: You can't mix named and traditional ? placeholders. You have 2 named parameter(s) and 1 traditonal placeholder(s)`
```

So it understands `:id` and `:description` just fine.  But for some reason it thinks `[Supervisory?]` contains a positional(traditional) placeholder instead of just a column name.

So when I call `getJddbcTemplate().batchUpdate(myInsertQuery, queryParams);` How do I indicate that the **?** character should be ignored?

**Exception:**

```java
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: You can't mix named and traditional ? placeholders. You have 2 named parameter(s) and 1 traditonal placeholder(s) in [INSERT INTO [Supervisory Description]([Supervisory?], Description) VALUES ( :id, :description )]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterUtils.buildValueArray(NamedParameterUtils.java:316)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterBatchUpdateUtils$1.setValues(NamedParameterBatchUpdateUtils.java:45)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:899)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:890)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:589)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:617)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(JdbcTemplate.java:890)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterBatchUpdateUtils.executeBatchUpdateWithNamedParameters(NamedParameterBatchUpdateUtils.java:40)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:324)
    at us.ak.state.revenue.cssd.AccessImport.dao.BaseHibernateDAO.batchInsert(BaseHibernateDAO.java:163)
    at WICKET_us.ak.state.revenue.cssd.AccessImport.dao.BaseHibernateDAO$$FastClassByCGLIB$$9a8099e8.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
    at org.apache.wicket.proxy.LazyInitProxyFactory$CGLibInterceptor.intercept(LazyInitProxyFactory.java:333)
    at WICKET_us.ak.state.revenue.cssd.AccessImport.dao.importers.SupervisoryDescriptionImporterDAO$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$36bf57cd.batchInsert(<generated>)
    at us.ak.state.revenue.cssd.AccessImport.dao.AccessExporter.typeProcessor(AccessExporter.java:88)
    at us.ak.state.revenue.cssd.AccessImport.dao.AccessExporter.process(AccessExporter.java:61)
    at us.ak.state.revenue.cssd.AccessImport.dao.AccessExporter$$FastClassByCGLIB$$9f5e6d3c.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
    at us.ak.state.revenue.cssd.AccessImport.dao.AccessExporter$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2ad77846.process(<generated>)
    at WICKET_us.ak.state.revenue.cssd.AccessImport.dao.AccessExporter$$FastClassByCGLIB$$9f5e6d3c.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
    at org.apache.wicket.proxy.LazyInitProxyFactory$CGLibInterceptor.intercept(LazyInitProxyFactory.java:333)
    at WICKET_us.ak.state.revenue.cssd.AccessImport.dao.AccessExporter$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$5edf35b8.process(<generated>)
    at us.ak.state.revenue.cssd.AccessImport.dao.AccessExporterTest.testProcess(AccessExporterTest.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:77)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

**EDIT:**
Thanks to the information from @tieTYT I tried adding `{espace \\}` to the end of my string and changing my column name to [Superverisory\?] in the query.  It didn't work.  Turns out the problem is Spring Specific.  The excepetion is being thrown by *Spring**'s `NamedParameterUtils.buildValueArray` It's trying to convert a query with named parameters to one only using traditional parameters and it's choking on my **?** and doesn't understand that it isn't a *Traditional* Parameter.

Comment: Have you considered fixing the column name? It's broken and violates rules for identifiers, best practices, and common sense.

Comment: I didn't design the database. This is a temporary program to do a batch import of data from a MS Access File to an SQL Server DB.  For simplicities sake I'm keeping the layout the same on the server as the file.  I'm working on a separate application to eliminate the MS Access file in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the Problem is with how **Spring** Handles the ? when using `NamedParamaterJdbcTemplate` the solution was to switch to using the regular `JdbcTemplate` create any Necessary RowMappers and handle it myself.

So now I'm using:

```java
List<Object[]> li = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
for(T t : list) { li.add(toObjectArr(t)); } //toObject converts my Pojo to Object[]

JdbcTemplate template = (JdbcTemplate)getJdbcTemplate().getJdbcOperations();
//paramconverter is a pre-compiled regex that matches :\w*
String insert = paramConverter.matcher(getInsertQuery()).replaceAll("?");

template.batchUpdate(insert, li);
```

Answer (score 1):

While the naming convention is extremely terrible, it will still work in SQL Server.  Enclosed is a temporary table in tempdb that I create, insert data, and select from.

[image]

```
-- Create a badly named table
create table tempdb.dbo.[Supervisory Description]
(
  [Supervisory?] int, 
  [Description] varchar(255)
);
go

-- Insert the data
insert into  tempdb.dbo.[Supervisory Description]
([Supervisory?], [Description]) values (1, 'This is fun');
go

-- Show the data
select * from tempdb.dbo.[Supervisory Description];
Go
```

Creating an MS Access table by hand with the same names and changing the SQL code around a little works fine also.

[image]

I think the issue is with DAO/Java.  It is thinking that the ? is a place holder.

Did you try turning on **quoted identifiers**.  This is a session level setting.  This will allow you to replace [] with " ".

This might make the DAO layer ignore the bad field name.

```
-- Set quoted identifier on
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
```

ANOTHER solution is to create a **view in MS Access that renames the field**.  That is why the 'Select Data' query is showing up under tables.

Then have the Java program go against the view.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

According to [this reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/statement.html#999472), there is a language independent way to do this in general, but I don't see a way to use it on a table/column name.

It's hard to find this in the official documentation, but [I've found this article](http://www.informit.com/library/content.aspx?b=STY_Sql_Server_7&seqNum=89) and it seems to say that a identifier name with a `?` in it is invalid.

> You can use the following symbols after the first character: #, $, and _.